# Load css element already rotated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an animation using CSS that will pop up and rotate when the page is loaded. The issue I'm having with is, I need the element to be rotated BEFORE the animation begins.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4o1w01q5/

I can't tell if the issue is with this CSS snippet:

```
        .container {
            background:red;
            background-image: url(img/2012-04-12_14-06-35_758-1.jpg);
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            padding:240px;
            padding-left: 300px;
            padding-right: 300px;
            padding-top:10px;
            -webkit-animation: logo-appear 0.6s, logo-rotate 1.6s;
            -moz-animation: logo-appear 0.6s, logo-rotate 1.6s;
            animation: logo-appear 0.6s, logo-rotate 1.6s;
        }
```

Or if there is a way to set the rotated positiong with jQuery. Any suggestions?

**Edit:** To clarify, what I'm trying to do is

1. Have a div load, rotated 45 degrees
2. Pop the div (logo-appear)
3. Rotate the div 45 degrees down (logo-rotate)

Why do I want it like this? I want a diamond-shaped element load and the rotate it to make it a square.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the problem...what do you mean by "rotated BEFORE the animation?"

Comment: What do you want the shapes to look like onload? horizontal or on an angle? and what do you want the end state to be?

Comment: Is this `-webkit-animation: logo-appear 0.6s, logo-rotate 0s;` what you'd like to achieve ? ( rotation in 0 seconds )

Comment: This might help you out.. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It was a matter of having the rotate happen along with the popping up sequence.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s8hae5dz/ with additional animation

Previous example:

```
@-webkit-keyframes logo-appear{                            
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    100% {    
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

Currently:

```
@-webkit-keyframes logo-appear{                            
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5) rotate(-45deg);
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-45deg);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-45deg);
    }
    100% {    
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(-45deg);
    }
}
```